# How to turn off "this website wants to run the following add-on.." in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm using Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 Professional. I have installed the Flash player add-on. But I allow Flash only for specific websites. When I open all other websites there's a message:

> This website wants to run the following add-on..

How can I turn off or disable this message?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found in IE9 is to click on the silly little gear icon in the upper right corner, then Safety, then ActiveX Filtering.  This replaces the obnoxious popup on every page with a small blue "NO" symbol to the right of the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to migrate back to IE8, where the notification is in a thin much less obnoxious line at the top of the screen. Having to always answer this question if you don't want flash on every screen is not acceptable.

Comment: your answer, besides very small, is oppinion based. please try to be more objective.

Answer (score -1):

Open Internet Options, by using Tools in IE or Control Panel, go to the security tab, be sure "Internet" icon is highlighted at the top, if the Default Level button is active, click it to reset settings to default level, then hit OK See if this solves it.

Or you can use the Reset all zones to default level button

Restart IE for changes to take effect.

.
[image]

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. What is wanted is a way to make IE9 *stop* requesting privileges for the sites. NOT to grant privileges. The answer to "how do I get out of saying NO every time" is not "say yes".